# Facing a problem to display elements from database to table

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I am trying to create a desktop application where I add/remove and etc.. my employees. I am using SQLite for database, JavaFX/Scene builder for app. So I created a TableView with 4 columns. For every single column I gave their personal ID. However, I can't see information in my window. Also, I'm receiving an error:

> Something went wrong...[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "VALUES": syntax error)

And guess what I have database - not even empty.
[image]

Here's part of my code where I try to reach information from DB and display in screen.

```
@FXML
private void pasalintiDarbuotojaVeiksmas() {
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\db\\darbuotojuDB.db");
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        String insert = "SELECT * FROM darbuotojai  (Vardas, Pavarde, Amzius, Kalba) VALUES ("+ dVardas + " " + dPavarde + " " + dAmzius + " " + dKalba + ")";
        int a = statement.executeUpdate(insert);
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong..." + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is my table where I want to see all information from database.
[image]

Comment: With insert you insert data in the database. To get data from database use select. Is this the wrong code or the wrong question?

Comment: You may need to enclose your values in single-quotes? Also, they need to be comma delimited. The literal syntax of the VALUES section you want to send to the server ultimately requires this syntax: ".. VALUES ('value1','value2','value3'...)

Comment: @RalfRenz My mistake, tried to update code and copied the wrong one. Sorry. There must be select * from darbuotojai

Comment: The `SELECT` syntax does not include `VALUES`. (Specifying those in a query would make little sense and this is not a update query either.)

Comment: Seems my sql knowledge not so good as I thought.. At least now I know that my query is bad.

Comment: Still having a problem to write a query. Maybe someone can help :?

Comment: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/select/

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. Your `insert` line should look like this:

`String insert = "INSERT INTO darbuotojai (Vardas, Pavarde, Amzius, Kalba) VALUES ("+ dVardas + ", " + dPavarde + ", " + dAmzius + ", " + dKalba + ")";`

Or if you want to get data from DB:

`String select = "SELECT * FROM darbuotojai";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);`

Answer (score 0):

try to change String insert:`String insert = String.format("SELECT * FROM darbuotojai  (Vardas, Pavarde, Amzius, Kalba) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", dVardas,dPavarde,dAmzius,dKalba);`

Comment: Same error as mentioned before:Something went wrong...[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "VALUES": syntax error)